# exctracting a tar file and excluding certain directories and files

Tags: chef-infra

I am new on chef can someone please help me get my syntax right or the proper way of going about doing the below:

```
remote_file '/tmp/apache-tomcat-8.0.43.tar.gz' do
   source 'http://csjh****1:8000/Tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.0.43.tar.gz'
   user 'root'
   group 'root'
   mode '0755'
   action :create
end

directory '/Apps/Dev/Tomcat/8.0.43' do
    recursive true
    mode 0755
    action :create
end

execute 'extract_some_tar' do
    command = 'tar -xzvf /tmp/apache-tomcat-8.0.43.tar.gz --strip-
    components=1'
    command =  '--exclude=*webapps/examples* '
    command = '--exclude=*webapps/ROOT*'
    command = '--exclude=*webapps/ROOT*'
    cwd '/Apps/Dev/Tomcat/8.0.43'
end
```

I am getting the below error from my kitchen:

```
     ================================================================================
       Error executing action `run` on resource 'execute[extract tomcat tarball]'
       ================================================================================

       Errno::ENOENT
       -------------
       No such file or directory - extract

       Resource Declaration:
       ---------------------
       # In /tmp/kitchen/cache/cookbooks/last_test/recipes/default.rb
```

Answer (score 0):

There should be no `=` after the `command`, you can also split your long string by adding `\` to the end of each line.

```
execute 'extract_some_tar' do
  command 'tar -xzvf /tmp/apache-tomcat-8.0.43.tar.gz '\
    '--strip-components=1 --exclude=*webapps/examples* '\
    '--exclude=*webapps/ROOT* --exclude=*webapps/ROOT*'
  cwd '/Apps/Dev/Tomcat/8.0.43'
end
```

Make sure you add some guard to the `execute` resource, otherwise it will be executed on every Chef run.

Comment: Hi Draco, I Tried your command it does not remove the directories. so here I am trying to extract and strip everything onto the directory '/Apps/Dev/Tomcat/8.0.43' excluding "examples ; ROOT ; docs"